# Are there any seemingly opposites (e.g. negation) in Spanish which, in fact, mean something different?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones-fijas

To illustrate what I'm referring to, I'd like to give to examples in English:

While *must not* seems to be the opposite of *must*, it has a different meaning. *Must go to school*, for example, means I have to go to school, while *must not go to school* indicates that I am not allowed.

Another similar negation which is not truly the opposite is *about to* and *not about to*. When I say *I'm about to leave* I am gonna do soon. But saying *I'm not about to* means they I definitely won't do it. So, it's not quite the opposite.

If someone is not aware of these differences, he certainly will use them incorrectly.

Q: I wonder if there are similar examples in Spanish, which language learners will run into if they don't know.

Comment: Well, "No tienes que quedarte a dormir" means "Tienes que quedarte a dormir" :) But I don't know if that is intrinsic to Spanish.

Comment: So, more seriously,  I guess you are looking for non-idiomatic expressions. Also without sarcasm, since otherwise the list would be practically infinite. Is the question equivalent to "when does `verb+no` lead to a meaning different from the  negation of the verb?"?

Comment: @c.p. ¿En qué contexto "No tienes que quedarte a dormir" significa "Tienes que quedarte a dormir"? Para mí este no sería un ejemplo de lo que se menciona en la pregunta.

Comment: @lorddarkangel Bueno, por eso no contesté la pregunta. El contexto es "No tienes que quedarte a dormir, puedes ir con tus amigos a tomar cerveza"  Significa lo contrario :D

Comment: @lorddarkangel Alguna gente piensa que los españoles suelen ser un poco hipócrita y te piden cosas esperando que hagas lo contrario: "No, para nada molestáis, quedaos un poco más". De ahí la broma.

Answer (score 1):

I have always thought that spanish is a bit ambiguous in those kind of expressions.

In most cases, "No debes comértelo todo" means that your obligation is not to eat everything instead of the lack of obligation.

I don't know if this other example is what you are looking for, but the use of "nadie" ("nobody") is also complicated:

"No se lo cuentes a nadie." => "Don't tell to anyone". // The double negation means actually a negation

"Nadie debe enterarse" => "Nobody must know" // Single negation means negation